# How can I find duplicate records in clickhouse

Tags: sql, duplicates, clickhouse

I want to know how I can find **duplicate data entries** within one table in **clickhouse**.

I am actually  investigating on a [merge tree table](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/mergetree/) and actually threw [optimize statements](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/optimize/) at my table but that didn't do the trick. The duplicate entries still persist.

Preferred would be to have a universal strategy without referencing individual column names.

I only want to see the duplicate entries, since I am working on very large tables.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The straight forward way would be to run this query.

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    count() AS cnt
FROM myDB.myTable
GROUP BY *
HAVING cnt > 1
ORDER BY date ASC
```

If that query gets to big you can run it in pieces.

```
SELECT 
    *,
    count() AS cnt
FROM myDB.myTable
WHERE (date >= '2020-08-01') AND (date < '2020-09-01')
GROUP BY *
HAVING cnt > 1
ORDER BY date ASC
```